# How do i connect wordpress login to codeignitor 3 app?

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter-3

I have one WordPress site and an app in codeignitor, App uses its own database to store user and plan details.
Now I want to simplify it like My user can log in to my WordPress website and after successful login I want the login information to forward to the app so that the user can go to the app.

Directory structure:

1. For Worpress =>  root->wordpress
2. For App  => root->app

On the same domain hosting.

I want the user's to use WordPress login to access App and manage their profile.

No idea how to proceed. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The most logical way to do this may be to use the cURL. Still, it is impossible to do so because such solutions cannot launch cookies or sessions in your browser and eject your client (essentially a security mechanism). You can try to resolve this by redirecting a user, or the most logical way is to use [wordpress api](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) support or capture the data using XML-RPC.

As an update. If both sides are on the same domain, you can try to eject the cookie or the session to the side you want to log in to. If it is under different domains, unfortunately, this suggestion will not work.